# YARN : 1/1 local-dirs are bad Alert

Tags: yarnpkg

I have an issue where all 3 node managers in my cluster are marked as bad with **local dirs bad** alerts.

I have seen many answers where it says, this error is due to YARN reaching its maximum default disk threshold which is 90%, but I can assure I have plenty of space on the YARN disk. **(just 35% of the disk is used)**. I suspect the YARN directory is corrupted.

Does anyone know of this alert/solution other than YARN reaching its disk threshold value??

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this issue.
There was no write permission on the folder to other users except OWNER, I granted the write permission on YARN folder to YARN and I could run the map reduce job. All 3 node managers are healthy now.

Comment: How did you grant the permission? I mean could you mention the steps?

Answer (score 0):

There are also other scenarios when this would happen:

- disk is bad or going bad
- disk has space, but has exhausted it's inodes
- disk was mounted read-only
- disk is a NFS mounted and the NFS server is down or lost connectivity